# LAMP server couldn't be installed using tasksel

Tags: permissions, lamp, tasksel

I tried to install LAMP server using tasksel.
But it shows the following error message.
I tried changing permissions using chmod but in vain

```
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied
tasksel: debconf failed to run
```

How can it be resolved?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the used command to install LAMP and the used `chmod` command.

Comment: i just typed tasksel and selected LAMP server and pressed tab and enter. the result is the following error messages.

Comment: With our without sudo?

Comment: without sudo. le me try with sudo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each system-wide installation needs root-rights. Run

```
sudo tasksel
```

and make your choice or run

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

to install LAMP.